# index rich documents using solrcell and tika

Tags: indexing, solr, apache-tika, cloudera-manager

I am a newbee in Solr search and currently working to get solr Cell work with Tika. Consider the following text file:

```
Name:                    Popeye
Nationality:             American
```

I would like Solr to return me two fields named 'name' and 'nationality' with the values popeye and american. To do this, I define two fields in my schema.xml file as

```
   <field name="name" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
   <field name="nationality" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true"/>
```

The text_general field is defined as

```
<fieldType name="text_general" class="solr.TextField" positionIncrementGap="100">
  <analyzer type="index">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <!-- in this example, we will only use synonyms at query time
                 <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="index_synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="false"/>
    -->
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
  <analyzer type="query">
    <tokenizer class="solr.StandardTokenizerFactory"/>
    <filter class="solr.StopFilterFactory" ignoreCase="true" words="stopwords.txt" enablePositionIncrements="true" />
    <filter class="solr.SynonymFilterFactory" synonyms="synonyms.txt" ignoreCase="true" expand="true"/>
    <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
  </analyzer>
</fieldType>
```

In the solrconfig.xml file, I define the update/extract method

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract" class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
    <str name="lowernames">true</str>
    <str name="uprefix">attr_</str>
    <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
```

Finally, I run the command to index the document as

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/popeye_bio_collection_shard1_replica1/update/extract?literal.id=doc1&commit=true' -F "myfile=@/tmp/popeye_bio.txt"
```

The document gets indexed without error. When I use the query command as

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/popeye_bio_collection_shard1_replica1/select?q=*%3A*&wt=json&indent=true'
```

I get the output as

```
    {
    "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":3,
    "params":{
      "indent":"true",
      "q":"*:*",
      "wt":"json"}},
      "response":{"numFound":1,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "attr_meta":["stream_source_info",
          "myfile",
          "stream_content_type",
          "text/plain",
          "stream_size",
          "206",
          "Content-Encoding",
          "windows-1252",
          "stream_name",
          "popeye_bio.txt",
          "Content-Type",
          "text/plain; charset=windows-1252"],
        "id":"doc1",
        "attr_stream_source_info":["myfile"],
        "attr_stream_content_type":["text/plain"],
        "attr_stream_size":["206"],
        "attr_content_encoding":["windows-1252"],
        "attr_stream_name":["popeye_bio.txt"],
        "attr_content_type":["text/plain; charset=windows-1252"],
        "attr_content":[" \n \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n \n  Name:                    Popeye\r\nNationality:             American\r\n \n  "],
        "_version_":1567726521681969152}]
  }}
```

As you can see, popeye and american are not indexed in the fields I have defined in the schema.xml file. What am I doing wrong here? I have tried changing the tokenizer as in text_general field type as `<tokenizer class="solr.PatternTokenizerFactory" pattern=": "/>`. But it does not make any difference. I would appreciate any help in this regard!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you define a tokenizer you're just indicating to Solr that *all* the data that is sent in that field should be tokenized/processed with your configuration, but in the end, you're sending all your information into **one** field.

Solr assumes that your data is structured (1 document that has fields). So one analyzer/tokenizer can't create more fields. The function of an analyzer/tokenizer is basically just tokenizing and transforming the text that is going into the inverted index for searching.

What you can do is use the `ScriptUpdateProcessor` and define a pipeline to do your modifications (split one field into several) before the text get's into the tokenizer. Something like:

```
<processor class="solr.StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory">
    <str name="script">splitField.js</str>
</processor>
```

And the `splitField.js` file could have something like:

```
function processAdd(cmd) {
    doc = cmd.solrDoc;  // org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument
    field = doc.getFieldValue("attr_content");

    // split your attr_content text into two variables:
    // name and nationality, then

    doc.setField("name", name);
    doc.setField("nationality", nationality);
}
```

In an ideal world this should be handled outside of Solr, but with the `ScriptUpdateProcessor` you can accomplish what you want.

Comment: Glad it helped! the only drawbacks of this approach is that you need to split the values yourself using javascript :)

Comment: Hi Jorge, I have implemented the idea you suggested. While indexing, I get an error `ReferenceError: "name" is not defined.` Any idea, what might be causing it?  How does the `doc.setField` recognizes name and nationality? Perhaps we should use the `field` variable somewhere. I call the java script in the update/extract method.

Comment: Yep but you're sending the data after the extraction right? the `name` and `nationality` fields needs to be defined on your `schema.xml`. Of course in my case I set the variables `name` and `nationality` as example of variables that you extract from the field, so `field = doc.getFieldValue("attr_content")` will extract the content of the `attr_content` field, you then split this text value into two different variables: `name` and `nationality`.

Comment: Hi Jorge! Please find my response in the answer section.

Answer (score 0):

The way I currently do it is to define a ´update.chain´ inside the update/extract method

```
<requestHandler name="/update/extract" class="solr.extraction.ExtractingRequestHandler" >
    <lst name="defaults">
<str name="update.chain">mychain</str>
    <str name="lowernames">true</str>
    <str name="uprefix">attr_</str>
    <str name="captureAttr">true</str>
```

where `mychain` is

```
<updateRequestProcessorChain name="mychain">
     <processor class="solr.StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory">
            <str name="script">splitField.js</str>
     </processor>
  <processor class="solr.LogUpdateProcessorFactory" />
  <processor class="solr.RunUpdateProcessorFactory" />
</updateRequestProcessorChain>
```

I included it inside the update/extract method, so that the processor gets called. If I understand you correctly, I should call the processor after `update/extract` method and before the text is sent to the tokenizer. If so, then how would the processor be called?

I also tried removing the `<str name="update.chain">mychain</str>` line from `update/extract` and then calling

```
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/popeye_bio_collection_shard1_replica1/update/extract?literal.id=doc1&update.chain=mychain&commit=true' -F "myfile=@/tmp/popeye_bio.txt"
```

I get the same error. splitFiled.js is defined as

```
function processAdd(cmd) {
doc = cmd.solrDoc; // org.apache.solr.common.SolrInputDocument
field = doc.getFieldValue("attr_content");
// split your attr_content text into two variables:
// name and nationality, then
doc.setField("name", name);
doc.setField("nationality", nationality);
}

function processDelete(cmd) {
}

function processMergeIndexes(cmd) {
}

function processCommit(cmd) {
}

function processRollback(cmd) {
}

function finish() {
}
```

The error occurs in the `setField`line. Is there any way I could print the ´field´ in console? Perhaps, ´console.log´ method?

Comment: Check [this documentation] you always need to end your chain with: `RunUpdateProcessorFactory` so that the document get's pushed to the index, otherwise the document never get's added. Can you share the code of your `splitField.js`? you should have added the logic to parsing your text into `name` and `nationality`.

Comment: Hi Jorge, I figured the thing with the `RunUpdateProcessorFactory`. I also add `LogUpdateProcessorFactory`. I could not see the link you sent me. Could you send it to me again. I am currently following this [link](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/ScriptUpdateProcessor). Please find the splitField.js code in the answer section.

Comment: This is the info https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Update+Request+Processors and http://lucene.apache.org/solr/6_5_0/solr-core/org/apache/solr/update/processor/StatelessScriptUpdateProcessorFactory.html but your error is that you need to define in you script the `name` and `nationality` variables, the `field` variable contains `" \n \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n \n  Name:                    Popeye\r\nNationality:             American\r\n \n  "` you need to split this string into the variables `name` and `nationality` just do some regex/split and define the variables.

Comment: something like: `parts = field.split('\r\n'); var name = parts[0].trim().split(":")[1].trim(); var nationality = parts[1].trim().split(":")[1].trim()` but keep in mind that this has to work for each document you send into Solr

Comment: Glad that worked! remember that I just used your example document to prove a point, you should generalize that into a more generic solution for your documents